# Add index on first page using Mpdf

Tags: php, mpdf

I want to add an index to my PDF and try to use the InsertIndex function from Mpdf for this, using this code.

```php
$questionLists = $this->render('question-list/pdf', ['post' => $questionList, 'style' => $styles]);


$mpdf->WriteHTML($questionLists);
$mpdf->InsertIndex(false);

return $mpdf->Output();
```

In the code, I loop trough a recursive twig template that is generating a lot of pages. That is added to the `WriteHTML` function from `Mpdf`. Now the code generates a nice Index. But the index is on the bottom of the pdf file.

I cannot replace the InsertIndex function (set it above the WriteHTML function) since there is nothing to index (since it did not add the HTML yet).

Is there a way to add an index at the first or second page of the PDF?
In the twig file I have added `<indexentry content="{{ post.title | raw }}" />`

Comment: I think you'll basically have to generate the entire content as an array, then generate the PDF from the array.  In that way you can first use the array's content to generate the Index at the start of the PDF

Comment: (This is a really good question, BTW!)